# How to find value in javascript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays like below.

```
array = [[false, 1, "label", "label value", null],[false, 2, "label1", "label1", null]]
```

I want to find the row matching to checkNum and return that row. checkNum is compared to the second index element.
I don't want to put a for loop something like below,

```
checkNum = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if ((array[i][1]) === checkNum) {
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have only one item in the array which match, or could there be more?

Comment: array.filter((row) => row[1] === checkNum)[0]

Answer (score 4):

Use `Array.filter()` to get an array of items that match the criteria, or `Array.find()` the get the 1st item that matches.

```js
const array = [[false, 1, "label", "label value", null],[false, 2, "label1", "label1", null]]
const checkNum = 1

console.log(array.filter(({ 1: n }) => n === checkNum)) // array of items
console.log(array.find(({ 1: n }) => n === checkNum)) // 1st item found
```

Comment: I think it's worth explaining what `{ 1: n }` is doing because it's not commonly used and may be new to some readers. The parameter passed to the filter predicate is an array (it's one of the elements of `array`, which is an array of arrays). What `{ 1: n }` is doing is an object-destructure of the array passed to the predicate. So, `{ 1: n }` is effectively the (0-based) 2nd element of the passed array. And, in the process of destructuring, it's stored in a variable named `n`. Hence the `n === checkNum` code tests the 2nd element of the filtered array element to see if it matches checkNum.

Answer (score 3):

You could find the item with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
var array = [[false, 1, "label", "label value", null], [false, 2, "label1", "label1", null]],
    checkNum = 1,
    result = array.find(a => a[1] === checkNum);

console.log(result);
```