# How to find string value in javascript array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm currently working off a previous question that I'm struggling to understand, where in this one I'm checking for the matching number, but I'd like to check for the string value given. I don't fully understand this below, any help would be appreciatted.

```
const arr = [["posts",{text: 'hello'}], ["likes", {text: 'liked'}],["comments", {text: 'commented'}]]

const check = 1;

console.log(arr.filter(({ 1: n }) => n === check))
```

but I'd like to check for a string value, example `check = "posts"`, if possible would you mind explaining as well? Much appreciated

[check related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871364/how-to-find-value-in-javascript-array-of-arrays)

Comment: please add what you like to compare. you hane more than one string in the structure ...

Comment: @NinaScholz only want to compare the strings in the arrays "posts"/"comments"/"likes", I don't want to search through the objects but only the first string in the array

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added the link to a similar question I've mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info. However what I understood from your question is you are trying to achieve the following:

```js
const arr = [
  ["posts", { text: "hello" }],
  ["likes", { text: "liked" }],
  ["comments", { text: "commented" }],
];
const check = "posts";

console.log(arr.filter((n) => n[0] === check));
```

Please also explore many other blogs for any functions you get confused in.

Comment: Anytime :) . i would highly encourage you to explore the functions when you encounter these small problems. They will give you better understanding.

Comment: I agree, I'll take that into consideration:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question fully, but is this what you're looking for? You simply need to choose first element in each array to compare.

```js
const arr = [["posts",{text: 'hello'}], ["likes", {text: 'liked'}],["comments", {text: 'commented'}]]

console.log(arr.filter(arr => arr[0] === "posts"))
```

Comment: Exactly what i understood from the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you so much!