# Array.find to update a value in a nested array

Tags: javascript

I created a basket in JavaScript, it works perfectly except for one thing:
When we add products to the basket, we select a quantity and everything goes well, but if we click again to add the same product, instead of modifying the quantity of the product, the same product is added to the localStorage.

To avoid this problem, I have to search for the product in the localStorage with the Array.find() method, if the product exists, I modify the quantity, otherwise I add it. But I don't know how to do it the right way yet

```js
let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('monPanier')) || [];
let wishlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myWishList')) || [];
let totalBasket = 0;
let nbrArticles;
let nbrWishlist;

function addBasket()
{
    
    let quantity_cart = $(".input_quantity"+$(this).data("id")).val();
    let name_article_cart = $(this).data("name");
    let idArticle = parseInt(this.id.replace("add_basket_btn_",""));
    let price_cart = $(this).data("price");
    let total_price_cart = (quantity_cart * price_cart);
    let newBasket = [idArticle,quantity_cart,name_article_cart,price_cart,total_price_cart];
    
    basket.push(newBasket);
    saveStorageBasket();
    loadStorageBasket();
    showBasket();
    calculeNbrArticle();
    console.log(newBasket);
}

function addWishlist()
{

    let name_article_wishlist = $(this).data("name");
    let idArticle = parseInt(this.id.replace("add_wishlist_btn_",""));
    let price_article_wishlist = $(this).data("price");
    
    let newWishlist = [idArticle,name_article_wishlist,price_article_wishlist];

    wishlist.push(newWishlist);
    saveStorageWishlist();
    loadStorageWishlist();
    showWishList();
    calculeNbrWishlist();
}

function showBasket() {
    //vider le panier 
    $("#basket").empty();
    totalBasket = 0;
    
    for(let i=0; i < basket.length; i++)
    {
        totalBasket = totalBasket + basket[i][4];
        
         $("#basket").append("<tr><td>"+basket[i][1]+"</td>"
                                  +"<td>"+basket[i][2]+"</td>"
                                  +"<td>"+basket[i][3]+"€</td>"
                                  +"<td>"+basket[i][4]+"€</td>"
                                  +"<td><button data-id='"+i+"' class='btn_cancel_basket'>supprimer</button></td>"
                                  +"</tr>");
    }
    // installer un event
    $("#basket button.btn_cancel_basket").on("click",suppArticleBasket);
    $("#totalBasket").text(totalBasket+" €");
    
}

function suppArticleBasket()
{
    let index = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(index);
    basket.splice(index,1);
    
    saveStorageBasket();
    loadStorageBasket();
    showBasket();
    
}

function showWishList()
{
    for(let i=0; i < wishlist.length; i++)
    {
        $("#Wishlist").append("<tr><td>"+wishlist[i][1]+"</td>"
                                +"<td>"+wishlist[i][2]+"</td>"
                                +"</tr>");
    }
}

function emptyBasket()
{
    if(basket == null || basket == 0)
    {
        console.log("panier = true");
        return true;
    }else
    {
        console.log("panier = false");
        return false;
    }
}

function validateBasket()
{
    if(emptyBasket() == false)
    {
        loadStorageBasket();
    basket = JSON.stringify(basket); //js --> json 
    console.log($.get("index.php","action=appelAjax2&Basket="+basket+"&total="+totalBasket,resetBasket));
    }
}

function resetBasket(reponse){
    $("#confirmationcmd").html("<p>Commande validée.</p>");
    $("#basket").empty();
    basket.length = 0;
   
    localStorage.clear();
    loadStorageBasket();
    showBasket();
    totalBasket = 0;
    calculeNbrArticle();
}

function resetBasket2(reponse){
    $("#confirmationcmd").html("<p>Panier annulé.</p>");
    $("#basket").empty();
    basket.length = 0;
   
    localStorage.clear();
    loadStorageBasket();
    showBasket();
    totalBasket = 0;
    calculeNbrArticle();
}

function resetWishlist(reponse){
    $("#confirmationWishlist").html("<p>Wishlist remise à zéro.</p>");
    $("#wishlist").empty();
    wishlist.length = 0;
   
    localStorage.clear();
    loadStorageWishlist();
    showWishList();
    totalWishlist = 0;
    calculeNbrWishlist();
}

function saveStorageWishlist(){
    localStorage.setItem("myWishList", JSON.stringify(wishlist));
}

function loadStorageWishlist(){
    wishlist = localStorage.getItem("myWishList");
    
    if(wishlist == null)
    {
        wishlist =[];
    }
    else
    {
         wishlist = JSON.parse(wishlist);
    }
}

function calculeNbrWishlist()
{
    loadStorageWishlist();
    nbrWishlist = wishlist.length;
    $("#nbrWishlist").text("("+nbrWishlist+")");
}



function saveStorageBasket(){
    localStorage.setItem("monPanier", JSON.stringify(basket));
}

function loadStorageBasket(){
    basket = localStorage.getItem("monPanier");
    
    if(basket == null)
    {
        basket =[];
    }
    else
    {
         basket = JSON.parse(basket);
    }
}

function calculeNbrArticle()
{
    loadStorageBasket();
    nbrArticles = basket.length;
    $("#nbrArticles").text("("+nbrArticles+")");
}

$(function()
{
    calculeNbrArticle();
    calculeNbrWishlist();
    loadStorageBasket();
    loadStorageWishlist();
    showBasket();
    showWishList();
    $(".add_basket_btn").on('click',addBasket);
    $(".btn_wishlist").on('click',addWishlist);
    $("#validateButton").on('click',validateBasket);
    $("#resetButton").on('click',resetBasket2);
    $("#resetButtonWishlist").on('click',resetWishlist);
});
```

Comment: That's *a lot* of code you want us to debug for you.  What *specifically* is the problem you've encountered?  Where *specifically* do you search for an existing element in an array, and how *specifically* does that operation not work as expected?

Comment: thank you. 
ideally, when I add a product that is already in the cart, the quantity of the product should be added rather than adding a new line.
I apparently have to search for the product in the localStorage with the Array.find() method, if the product exists, we modify the quantity, otherwise we add it

Comment: I don't know what I should do. I don't know how to use this method that I didn't know, nor where I should use it, I'm new to JS

Comment: If you're new to JavaScript then tutorials/examples will be your best bet.  You can use your favorite search engine to help find those.  It sounds like you already have an idea of what you need to do, you just need to make an attempt and get started.  Things you'll want to research include reading data from local storage, using `.find()` to find a specific object from an array, updating a value in an object in an array, etc.  You are encouraged to try.

Comment: thanks guys ;) if someone have some ideas do not hesitate, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: See my solution below. This was a nice learning session for me, especially about local storage. Thanks for this. I have used one fixed article ID and shrank your code to have a minimal test setup. See it as a reference for your next post :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi christian, thank you for your help, i will try your code and see if i can adapt it on my project, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**The basic idea:**

- push the new basket array if empty
- check if the ID is already in the basket array

  - if so, update the quantity
  - if not, add the new basket

I have read the following learning resources about:

- for loops ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp))
- find ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))
- filter ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

According to what I have read [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871364/how-to-find-value-in-javascript-array-of-arrays) `Array.find` does not work because it finds only the first element. I used the suggested filter option.

**The essential part with changes:**

```
function updateQuantity(basket, newBasket, idArticle) 
{   
    // filter: search for articleId in array of arrays
  if (basket.filter(({ 1: n }) => n === idArticle)) {
      for(i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) {
        basket[i][1] += 1;
      } 
    } else {
      basket.push(newBasket)
    }
  }

function addBasket()
{
    let quantity_cart = 1
    let name_article_cart = "productName"
    let idArticle = 1
    let price_cart = 10
    let total_price_cart = (quantity_cart * price_cart);
    let newBasket = [idArticle,quantity_cart,name_article_cart,price_cart,total_price_cart];
    
    if (basket.length === 0) {
      basket.push(newBasket)
    }
    else
    {
     updateQuantity(basket, newBasket, idArticle)
    }
    console.log(basket)
}
```

**My complete test code:**

```js
let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('monPanier')) || [];
let totalBasket = 0;
let nbrArticles;

function updateQuantity(basket, newBasket, idArticle) 
{   
    // filter: search for articleId in array of arrays
  if (basket.filter(({ 1: n }) => n === idArticle)) {
      for(i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) {
        basket[i][1] += 1;
      } 
    } else {
      basket.push(newBasket)
    }
  }

function addBasket()
{
    let quantity_cart = 1
    let name_article_cart = "productName"
    let idArticle = 1
    let price_cart = 10
    let total_price_cart = (quantity_cart * price_cart);
    let newBasket = [idArticle,quantity_cart,name_article_cart,price_cart,total_price_cart];
    
    if (basket.length === 0) {
      basket.push(newBasket)
    }
    else
    {
     updateQuantity(basket, newBasket, idArticle)
    }
    console.log(basket)
}

function suppArticleBasket()
{
    let index = 1
    console.log(index);
    basket.splice(index,1);
    
    saveStorageBasket();
    loadStorageBasket(); 
}

function emptyBasket()
{
    if(basket == null || basket == 0)
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function saveStorageBasket(){
    localStorage.setItem("monPanier", JSON.stringify(basket));
}

function loadStorageBasket(){
    basket = localStorage.getItem("monPanier");
    
    if(basket == null)
    {
        basket =[];
    }
    else
    {
         basket = JSON.parse(basket);
    }
}

$(function()
{
    loadStorageBasket();
    $("#add_basket_btn").on('click',addBasket);
});
```

```html
<button id="add_basket_btn">Add</button>
```